# Is it possible to add/modify system include path without modifying cmake in clion?

Tags: clion, buildroot

I'm working on a cross-platform project which requires dependencies which are not available on my machine. I basically use a cross-platform tool-chain in docker to build everything. Using buildroot I build a whole Linux system for an ARM platform.
So, I was wondering if there is an option to let Clion know or pick another path for system include header files? Then at least clion can help with code completion etc.